# Trying to verify existence of PDF Document with Excel

Tags: excel, vba, http

I am attempting to check if a PDF doc exists online using an Excel Macro, at the minute I have the following code :

```
Function URLExists(url As String) As Boolean
Dim Request As Object
Dim ff As Integer
Dim rc As Variant

On Error GoTo EndNow
Set Request = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")

With Request
  .Open "GET", url, False
  .Send
  rc = .StatusText
End With
Set Request = Nothing
If rc = "OK" Then URLExists = True

Exit Function
EndNow:End Function
```

And then in my Excel Document I'm doing :

```
=urlexists(http://www.whatever.bleh/thepdfname.pdf)
```

The URLExists code I found after some Googling, it does seem to do something but always returns False, I assume because its not specifically for checking PDFs and so not really able to do what I want.  Is this possible?  I've found that the HTTP HEAD method will do what I want but I don't know if I can request similar in WinHTTPRequest.

Comment: Comment out the `On Error GoTo EndNow` and see if anything changes

Comment: Where online is the PDF stored?  If something like SharePoint then you might be running into permissions issues.  HEAD instead of GET should be fine.